# Facebook App: Nothing happens when trying to add domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication, facebook-app-settings

I've made a Facebook app to implement fecebook login on my php Saas solution.

I can't add a domain in the settings->advanced section.

A dialog is shown. I write the domain and click the [add] button. Now a spinner is showing and just keeps spinning. I've tried everal computers and mobile devices. It is the same everywhere.

What do I do wrong?

I have set the domains in then settings -> basic sections and I have added all the url callbacks.

[image af dialog with spinning button - with protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X62g.jpg)

EDIT: It is the same thing with or without protocol. The placeholder in the field states to enter an URL but either with or without the protocol part nothing happens.

[image af dialog with spinning button - without protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN5L7.jpg)

Comment: The value you entered is a URL, have you tried an actual domain (host name) only instead?

Comment: @CBroe : It is the same ting that happens. I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Same here, plus an error message in the browser console saying something went wrong with the AJAX request. Appears to be a bug that has been open for a while now, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/424762579480203/